# In create-react-app Bootstrap-react loading after my scripts, so my scripts have low priority

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In create-react-app Bootstrap-react loading after my scripts, so my scripts have low priority.
How can I change it? I don't know, because can't change webpack config of react-create-app.
In my main component I added:
    `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`
    `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';`
And after in my different componets I adding react-components like this:
    `import {
    Col,
    Navbar,
    Nav,
    NavItem
} from 'react-bootstrap'`

Comment: Can you show how you use Bootstrap-react? If you import some component like `import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'` to your App.js or other components there will be no problem with precedence.

Comment: @SergeyOrlov - I changed my question

Comment: What does low priority mean for scripts? Can you please share a project demonstrating the issue and describe what you expect vs what happens?

Comment: @DanAbramov. It's repository of project : https://github.com/AlexandrKnyazev1395/react-app-redux-express. 
Low priority mean that styles of tags that I have in my css files affect on bootstrap-components only if I add "!important" to every style.

Comment: For example, I want that <Button/> have background-color "red". I write this in my script and this work only if I write "Background-color :red !important;"